# Jenkins docker-pipeline plugin: docker.image.inside never finishes

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use the [docker-pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) plugin with the following groovy pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Some Impressive Stage Name") {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.image("alpine").inside() {
                        sh "echo 'hello world!'"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simple pipeline will never finish. I can confirm that the image is being pulled and run in less than two seconds, but the pipeline simply stalls on the `hello world` step. What am I doing wrong here?

I am running Jenkins version `2.401.1` and
docker-pipeline plugin version `563.vd5d2e5c4007f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the plugin by just using `docker run` instead of an old plugin. It's not pretty, but it works:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage() {
            steps {
                sh '''docker run 'alpine' \
                    sh -c '
                        echo "hello world!"
                    '
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously means that you have to manually inject environment variables, volumes, secrets, certificates etc. but you have full control over this and aren't at the mercy of some long forgotten jenkins plugin developer(s).

Of course you can use a separate dockerfile (or even a docker-compose file), but I prefer my CI pipeline script to be in one script rather than multiple files. So this is a solution for that scenario.